# APACHE NIFI Error message: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss', which cannot be converted to a timestamp"

Tags: apache-nifi

I have received a workflow in Nifi that converts logs from IBM-MQ to JSON format and it's supposed to put the information into an Oracle Database.
Each log line is parsed using ExtractGrok, and in the original parsing performed by the person who gave me the workflow, the format obtained is as follows: 'yyyy-MM-ddhh.mm.ss' when in fact there are other characters that the parsing ignores (probably It's in a TIMESTAMP format). The PutSQL Processor gets the error in the title (APACHE NIFI Error message:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss', which cannot be converted to a timestamp"), no matter how I parsed the time component, and i have done so in a variety of ways using JOLT (the picture contains 3 examples).
How do I get Nifi to put in the time field in the Oracle? Since I am new to Nifi I would be happy to a fairly detailed explanation so I can carry out the whole process with your helpful explanation.

Many many thanks to everyone who helps!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a dot and 3 zeros as milliseconds to the format (I used jolt transform) and by that transforming the format to the following: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS".

I saw the solution in an explanation that @Ben Yaakobi gave in another question here on stack overflow:
"The appended 3 zeros are since epoch in NiFi is in milliseconds."